# Calling sub class method in super class

Tags: java

My project contains some legacy code. It has two controllers with the same name in different packages.

Ex: `org.a.TestController` , `org.b.TestController`.

I have created sayHello() method in sub class as like below.

```
package org.b;

public class TestController extends org.a.TestController{

    public String sayHello(){ return "hello"; }

}
```

I am accessing sayHello() method in Base class, but i am confused which is the best way to access sub class method in base class. 
Every controller contains 5k lines of code with some static methods. I have tried below two ways.

1. `String s = new org.b.TestController().sayHello();`
2. `String s = ((org.b.TestControlle)this).sayHello();`

Please tell me what is difference between above two ways and which is the best way?.
Please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: How come your package statement also includes the name of the class? The full name of your class under this code is `org.b.TestController.TestController`.

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake my package org.b only

Answer (score 0):

The two ways that you are listing are performing the same call on different objects:

- `new org.b.TestController().sayHello();` creates a new `TestController` object,
- `((org.b.TestController)this)` uses `this` object to make a call. This will succeed only if `this` is actually `org.b.TestController` or one of its subclasses; otherwise, a cast exception would be thrown.

Although the result is the same because `sayHello()` does not reference any state associated with the object (i.e. it does not reference any fields of your object) the actions are fundamentally different.

**Note:** any non-private, non-static method of a superclass that has been overridden in a subclass would call the version from subclass, regardless of the location from which it is invoked. For example

```
class A {
    public void print() { System.out.println("Hello");}
    public void sayHello() { print(); }
}
class B extends A {
    public void print() { System.out.println("Hello, world!");}
}
...
B b = new B();
b.sayHello();
```

prints `"Hello, world!"`, even though `sayHello` invokes `print` in the superclass.

Comment: Actually, the second method is casting the superclass to an instance of the subclass, which will not work from what I can make of the question.

Comment: @bcsb1001 It's hard to say because there is not enough context. I assume that OP has tried it both ways, but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. in org.b.TestController some static methods and blocks are there, is any performance difference there in above two ways ?.

Comment: @user3073785 The biggest impact on performance is from creating the new instance inside `new org.b.TestController()`. The cast, on the other hand, amounts to a type check, and is very fast. Once you are inside the method, there is no difference in execution speed one way or the other.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks now i got the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to make a few assumptions in this answer.

1. You have a class `Base`, which you're doing some logic in. Let's call that method `Base#logic()`.
2. You have subclasses of `Base` -- `org.a.TestController` and `org.b.TestController`
3. `Base` and both `TestController`s implement `String sayHello()`

Then `Base#logic()` would just look like this:

```
void logic() {
    String s = this.sayHello();
    // ...
}
```

That's because the method lowest on the type hierarchy is invoked by default. You don't need to do anything explicitly. Just make sure that `Base` implements a `sayHello()` or is an abstract class with `public abstract String hello();` defined as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first line guaranteed to work. Your parent class may, but doesn't have to be an instance of a subclass. Say you have class  A and class B that extends A. In class B you have a method say methodB(). It is possible to do something like this:

```
A a = new B();
((B)a).methodB();
```

And in such case it will work. But if you do

```
A a = new A();
((B)a).methodB(); //Runtime ClassCastException will be thrown
```

Because your instance a in this case is not an instance of a B and thus doesn't know what methodB is. However, if anywhere in your code (doesn't matter which class) you do

```
new B().methodB();
```

It will always work since you just created a new instance of a B class and invoke its own method. The point is Parent doesn't have any knowledge of what extra methods do his children have while children always know what the parent has (except of private methods of the parent). If in your B class you will make your methodB static then of course you don't need to instanciate new instance of B and can just do

```
B.methodB();
```